# Twitterbootstrap dropdown, open modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog

Trying to get a dropdown button to open, and then when clicking on an item in the dropdown it should open a modal - but not working, added this code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">By industries <span class="caret"></span>
                  </button> 
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#consumergoods">Consumer goods</a></li>

                    <div class="modal fade" id="consumergoods" data-target="#consumergoods">
                                          <div class="modal-dialog">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                              <div class="modal-header orange">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title"><strong></strong>Consumer goods</h4>
                                              </div>
```

Probably doing something seriously wrong, but I'd be glad if someone could help, thanks!

Comment: For a start, the HTML you have posted is invalid. You haven't closed the `ul` and several `div` elements. Other than that, you haven't got your `data-*` and `id` values set up properly.

Comment: I did close those, but didn't copy them in. And okay!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have a wrapper div `.dropdown` for the `button` and `<ul>` for the dropdown to work and for the modal you need to give the attribute `data-toggle="modal"` to the link

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">By industries <span class="caret"></span>    
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#consumergoods" data-toggle="modal">Consumer goods</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="consumergoods" data-target="#consumergoods">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header orange">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>    
                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title"><strong></strong>Consumer goods</h4>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkk7Lv3e/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! However, I put the buttons in a buttongroup but they don't group anymore

Comment: @Bernie Oh, then you can remove that dropdown wrapper [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/dkk7Lv3e/2/)